# Google Chrome initial loading of AngularJS application

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, load

I have an AngularJS application which is reachable under this url:

[My appl](https://app.apotime.at/)

and it has a strange behaviour: it I write the URL of my application into URL input and press enter, with Google Chrome it takes about 20 seconds to load without opened developer tools (F12), if I open developer tools it takes about 5 seconds, which is ok. With other Browsers like opera, Firefox an IE it always takes about 5 seconds for initial load of application.

My question now would be if someone has any explanation about this strange behaviour?

Comment: Took 5 seconds on my google chrome. I think you might need to clear the cache of your google chrome.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have tried it in inkognito mode and it also took 5 sec (at every try). In normal mode somethimes it took 20 seconds. Is there a possibility at my application side to do something to improve the load time in "normal" mode? I recognized that it is also a difference if I click the link "My appl" (always 5 second) or I write the URL in Browser URL input and click enter. It's a little bit strange at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with slow response time is because you have too many file that are loading. Your application loads html file with `ng-include` and it doesn't start loading that file before all your scripts are loaded. I would suggest bundling all your scripts into one file. This would cut the loading time at least in half.
This is good plugin that bundles your libraries from bower into one file https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-bundle-assets.

Also good practice is putting static html in your html file that later will be replaced with the content you want

```
<body ng-include='app/core/aposoft.html'>
   <div> App is initializing </div>
</body>
```

With html like this you will let the user to know that the app is loading, you can style it better with css. 
Put all your scripts below `</body>` tag. Also enable caching on the server for all your scripts.

This way you have single file for loading all your scripts and initial html to show the user that your app is initializing and the next time same user opens your app it will be really fast.

Note: to avoid problem with cache when you have new version you should use https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-useref

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a guess, but it seems like you would be better of grunting/minifying the whole project into 3 files for total.

The project includes many .js files and thus takes more time.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TMKj0BxzVgw

Try this video, if you would make all these 246 requests into 3 requests by grunting/minifying that would do the trick

also, it currently takes max 5 seconds

Edit :

I found my own code again.

This is in the package.json

```
    "grunt": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-angular-templates": "^1.0.4",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-usemin": "^3.1.1",
```

It creates this tree folder tree :

```
 dist >
    css >
        css.min.css
    scripts >
        app.min.js
        vendor.min.js
```

Instead of my app folder containing more then 10 folders with .js files.

Index.html

```
    <!-- build:css css/css.min.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Something.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Something.css"></link>
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- build:js scripts/vendor.min.js -->
    <script src="Something.js"></script>
    <script src="Something.js"></script>
    <script src="Something.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- build:js scripts/app.min.js -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Something.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Something.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Something.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
```